# Record in Kafka 0.10 coming with contentType even after using app.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=raw

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have created a simple stream in spring cloud dataflow where I have http as source and kafka as sink.

```
stream create --definition "http --port=<yyyy> --path-pattern=/test  > :streamtest1" --name ingest_to_broker_from_http --deploy --properties app.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=raw
```

Even after using *app.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=raw*,
I am receiving Kafka messages with contentType application string.

cURL Command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"test6"}' http://<xxxx>:<yyyy>/test
```

Kafka Message:

> contentType "text/plain"originalContentType
>   "application/json;charset=UTF-8"{"name":"test6"}

- Am I passing the headerMode property in a correct way?
- What should I do to receive only the message (without header) in
  Kafka topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Changed the below property:

```
app.http.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=raw
```